# Aframe How do I simulate a 6dof controller on the Oculus GO controller using the touchpad to move the controller forward, back, left, and right?

Tags: aframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg5mY.jpg)What if we could simulate 6dof control on the Oculus Go controller? Imagine that we turn the controller 3d model into a hand, it still just rotates, but imagine that we use the touchpad to move the hand foward, left, right, or backwards in space, the touch pad gives you movement along a z and x axis in space, but the accelerometer/gyro gives you a y and x axis. so the accelerometer/gyro serves as the arm, and the touch pad serves as the hand/wrist, a hand that can move forward and back and only twist left and right, and grip with the trigger, the hand can't tilt up or down but the arm can make up for that. So how do I build this?

Answer (score 2):

There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-thumb-controls-component that provides events for pressing thumbpad in directions (e.g., `thumbupstart`, `thumbleftend`).

Write a component that listens to those events, sets a property (e.g., `this.buttons.left = true`, then the `tick` handler needs to update the `this.el.object3D.position` based on which buttons are held down.

Also need to take into consideration the direction the camera is facing. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/wasd-controls.js is a good starting point is it is similar, where it listens to key downs and translates position. Just need to modify to use thumb-controls instead.

More hints:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-thumb-controls-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-thumb-controls-component.min.js">

AFRAME.registerComponent('thumb-movement-controls', {
  init: function () {
    this.buttons = {
      left: false, right: false, up: false, down: false
    };

    this.el.addEventListener('thumbleftstart', () => {
      this.buttons.left = true;
    });

    this.el.addEventListener('thumbleftend', () => {
      this.buttons.left = false;
    });
  },

  tick: function () {
    // Really simplified movement. Does not take into account camera heading or velocity / time, but wasd-controls shows how.
    if (this.buttons.left) {
      this.el.position.x -= 0.001;
    }
  }
});

<a-entity daydream-controls thumb-controls thumb-movement-controls></a-entity>
```

Comment: Tonight 4 experienced web coders, javascript coders, worked together to try to follow your instructions to accomplish this goal with the daydream controller, we worked for 4 hours, and we tried so many different things, we created an in VR console to see what the daydream controller was doing. Still we couldn't get it to work. The difficultly rating for customizing a daydream controller in aframe seems pretty high, but I am wondering if it's just us or if this controller is particularly difficult. Would it have been easier to customize the trackpad on the Oculus Go?

Comment: It is the same process for each controller. I've attached another hint. 3D / controller work is quite different coming from webdev world. A-Frame abstracts a ton already by helping you grab / query the gamepad, the model, button events, and the thumb-controls is pretty complex on its own translating thumb axis to directional events :) ... Comment more if you get stuck on specific parts.

Comment: was able to get a trackpad left click to animate a box. but then we tried replace the box entity id with the camera entity id, and tried to make camera rotate 15 radians on a right trackpad click, thats not working. I also tried adding the Oculus Go controller code back into it and none of the new trackpad modifications we made are working with it. including when Solo controller code is commented out. figuring out finally how emit works proved to be a solution for both the controller and animating multiple entities. Almost there. I'm going to reexamine move controls component for clues. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that I can’t seem to combine thumb controls with teleport controls with the camera element with rotations my code is starting to feel like a nightmare, take a look http://silly-diver.glitch.me 

At one point I had the left trackpad triggering a box to split entities
At another point I had the teleport working but it was creating a left and right daydream controller during teleportation which was totally messed up.
Here is an older version of the code with the multiple entities animated, and these have subsequent animations upon a second trigger http://typhoon-rule.glitch.met